# Android 10 File info from scoped storage (get file extension from Uri)

Tags: android, uri, scoped-storage

**Problem**

I'm using this code to select single file from device (Mostly downloads folder).

```java
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        intent.type = "*/*"
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false)
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,getString(R.string.field_import_btn)), requestCode)
```

It works well i get Uri, and i'm able to read file through `contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)`

Problems occurs when i actually need to know what kind of file is this. 
In other words i need to know it's extension.

For this i could easily use:

```java
String type = resolver.getType(uri);
String extention = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(type);
```

But here's the problem: If file's format is at least slightly rarer `application/octet-stream`
as `type`.

Example: `SHP` aka Esri Shape file.

**Other Observations**
While in Nokia 8 Android Pie (28 api level)

Actual uri i get is:
`content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1470`

In Android 10 emulator for same type of file (Shp) i get:
`content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2FRO20.shp`

Which it self i possibly could use to get  that last part ".shp"

**Actual question**
So mainly i have two questions:

1. Is there a way to get exact file extension from Uri (no mime-type conversions back and forth)?
2. How reliably i can state that starting with 29 api level i can just parse file extension from uri it self without failure?

Comment: You can query for DISPLAY_NAME at the content resolver. Once you have the display name extract the extension.

Comment: Your intent is quite confusing using two actions.

Comment: LOL yeah. I kind of tried few options at same time. @blackapps i will try that.

Comment: @blackapps Yes that is working. Maybe you know where i could get full documentation to contentResolver possible queries?

Comment: You could read stackiverflow pages tagged like that or tagged mediastore.

Answer (score 2):

try below code to get the mime type of selected file. It will return as pdf jpeg png`
pass the uri of user selected file

```
  private fun getFileMimeType(uri: Uri): String? {
    return if (uri.scheme == ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT) {
        val mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
        mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(context.contentResolver.getType(uri))
    } else {
        MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(File(uri.path)).toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: First part of your solution never works with unknown extensions (they are identified as application/octet-stream)

Could you explain the second part? I know that `MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl` won't work with my first presented Uri, but what's with the all the redundant looking constructors?

Comment: Brilliant Answer, after too much effort finally get this :)